# Getting value from a number_field_tag in rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms

I am trying to grab a value that a user sets in a number field tag and pass it to a controller using a button.  Here is what I have so far:

```
<% if current_user && current_user.can_vote_for?(sound) %>
  <%= number_field_tag 'rating', nil, in: 1...4 %>
  <%= button_to "Rate", rate_sound_path(sound, value: params[:rating]), method: "post" %>
<% end %>
```

In the sounds controller:

```
  # Give the sound a rating
  def rate
    rating = current_user.sound_ratings.new(sound_id: params[:id], value: params[:value])
    if rating.save
      redirect_to '/sounds', notice: "Thank you for voting."
    else
      redirect_to '/sounds', alert: "Unable to vote, perhaps you already did."
  end
 end
```

Not sure what is going wrong.  I know the sound_ratings table is not being updated with the new ratings.

Not sure if this is helpful, but here is the sound_rating model:

```
class SoundRating < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to :sound
  belongs_to :user

  validates_uniqueness_of :sound_id, scope: :user_id
  validates_inclusion_of :value, in: [1, 4]
  validate :ensure_not_author

  def ensure_not_author
    errors.add :user_id, "is the author of the sound" if sound.user_id == user_id
  end
end
```

Any hints?

Comment: Inside the rate function looks like you are looking for a params[:value], shouldn't that be params[:rating] as per the post back? Also looks like `button_to` is a bit wrong, check out the examples here http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html